# Comparing dates in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT array_to_string(array( SELECT birthday from users where userid>10), ',' ) as birthdaylist
```

This generate for example the following data:

```
birthdaylist
text
"2015-08-02,2015-08-09"
```

What I want is to get this result:

```
("02/Aug/2015","09/Aug/2015")
```

I read the postgresql manual http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html I see there is a function `to_date('05 Dec 2000', 'DD Mon YYYY')` but it doesn't really help my case.

I tried:

```
Select Array (SELECT birthday from users where userid>10)
```

This query gave me an array but it's not a text array its: `date[]`
How do i get     `("02/Aug/2015","09/Aug/2015")` ?

Comment: The `to_char` function is mentioned on the same documentation page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overcomplicating your query. You don't need a nested sub-select. Just do a regular aggregation with the format you want.

```
select string_agg(to_char(birthday, 'DD Mon YYYY'), ',')
from users 
where userid > 10;
```

---

Btw: you should not read the manual for a completely outdated version (8.2). Always use the manual for the version you are using.